# How to override the new limited keyboard repeat rate limit?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I may be an alien around here, but here's my problem: the speed limit on old Ubuntu releases (= before 11) was very very fast. It was really great for me.

Now, on Ubuntu 11, they may have thought: "who will ever want that speed? Nobody! So let's put the maximum speed to a lower limit".

It's so stupid that they tried to narrow down the speed to some other famous OS. If Linux is more powerful, why remove some of its power? I don't get that.

So is there any way to override that speed limit and get my keyboard as fast as it is on other previous versions?

Comment: You mean the repeat rate, when you hold down a key?

Comment: @mateo_salta kbdrate doesn't work at all = has no effect on my keyboard: `sudo kbdrate -r 30.0 -d 1440` and `sudo kbdrate -r 2.0 -d 10` have same effect = nothing.

Comment: @psusi You're right I've changed the title

Comment: There are two Ubuntu releases whose numbers start with `11`--`11.04` and `11.10`. You may want to edit your question to clarify which one you are running.

Comment: Both releases: 11.04 and 11.10

Comment: Initially this question seemed like seeking a workaround.  Given some of the comments, I believe it is beginning to look more like a bug report.  This is off-topic per the [FAQ]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given that this issue hasn't been fixed yet, and can be very frustrating, I here's a workaround:

Initially I used `xset r rate`, but the problem with it is that it's not persistent after sleep/awake, and sometimes the desktop reverts to limited rate at random times (probably gnome settings daemon does something which causes reinforcing the settings).

I was uselessly changing my old gconf keyboard settings, only to discover that the setting has been migrated to gsettings. The value limit is hardcoded in the system settings application (`gnome-control-center` in file `./panels/keyboard/gnome-keyboard-panel.ui:877`).

You can easily override it:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard repeat-interval 15
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard delay 150
```

As long as you don't change your settings from the gui, this setting should be persistent.

Comment: This is a really good answer, and as soon as I can test it I'll verify if it works, and if so I'll check your answer as good. But I've reverted back to Ubuntu 10.04 which is far more stable, better, faster and friendlier than all other versions (from my point of view)

Comment: this worked great for me

Comment: Ok your answer works but depends of the distributions. For me it was: `gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard repeat-interval 20` and `gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard delay 150`

Comment: Great solution! What are the defaults though, if someone were to set it back?

Comment: No such key in Ubuntu 16.04 anymore. Anyone know how to do it in the new Ubuntu version??

Comment: current solution is in answer below from Erik Olofsson  ...  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat-interval  17

Answer (score 25):

In Ubuntu 15.10 and later the settings have moved.

To get approximately 90 cps repeat rate and 150 ms delay:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay 150
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat-interval 11
```

At these high repeat rates I would recommend to stay as close to a multiple of your screen refresh rate as possible. This will help you stop at the wanted location as the movement is easier to follow.

If we take the default example of a 60 Hz display this works out to one of these repeat intervals:

```
30  cps = 1000/30  ≈ 33 ms (30.3  cps)
60  cps = 1000/60  ≈ 16 ms (62.5  cps)
90  cps = 1000/90  ≈ 11 ms (90.9  cps)
120 cps = 1000/120 ≈ 8  ms (125.0 cps)
```

Comment: thanks, this works for me. I cannot use the above ones include `org.gnome.settings-daemon` ones.

Comment: This works on 16.04

Comment: vote up this answer this is the right one for 16.06 LTS

Comment: Strangely neither the setting in the preferences panel nor this one had any effect. Only `xset` worked for me. Could there be any reason for that?

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 18.04. I find 200/20 best combination for delay/repeat rate.

Answer (score 14):

You can temporarily override Ubuntu's max keyboard rate using the `xset` command if you're using GNOME 3 on Ubuntu > 10.04.  Example:

```
xset r rate 220 160
```

You can also try adding (uncomenting) the following in `/etc/kbd/config`:

`KEYBOARD_RATE="160"`

`KEYBOARD_DELAY="220"`

Edit: corrected an inconsistency in the examples.

Comment: Hi, have you any idea on how to put set it at start so that it's set for every applications I may launch? Thank you

Comment: uncomment the following in /etc/kbd/config:

    KEYBOARD_RATE="220"

    KEYBOARD_DELAY="160"

Comment: Also see: http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/kbdrate8.html

Comment: Isn't it 'r rate [delay [rate]]' meaning that in your example KEYBOARD_DELAY="220" KEYBOARDD_RATE="160"?

Comment: Oh, yes, that is correct. I've edited the example to make it consistent.

Comment: There's no file `/etc/kbd/config` and I don't think it's working when I create one. Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: What is the output of: $ sudo ls -lh /etc/kbd/

Comment: @jarederaj

    total 4.0K
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40 Feb  4 16:03 config

Comment: ls: cannot access '/etc/kbd/': No such file or directory

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me while the upper answers didn't seem to.

Answer (score 2):

Go to *System-> Preferences-> Keyboard*, and adjust the *Repeat Keys* `Speed` slider to the far right. On later systems you access this control using the Unity Launcher's *System Settings*--the button with the wrench. The control panel is the same.

Comment: I presume that's the dialog box he's already referring to.

Comment: @neon_overload, who is referring to what box where?  There is no mention of a box in the question.

Comment: He says that the maximum speed Ubuntu is allowing him to set is too low.  Unless I see otherwise I presume he's talking about the regular keyboard settings dialog in Ubuntu.

Comment: @neon_overload, he doesn't mention setting anything anywhere, just that the speed is lower.

Comment: The control panel is the same, but the keyboard repeat rate is *lower*.

Comment: @OlivierPons, you mean it looks like it is in about the same place as before?  Is it all the way up?  How much slower is it?

Comment: @OlivierPons, when I turn the knob up to full and run `wc -c` in a terminal, then hold down a key for 15 seconds, then hit ctrl-d to end, I get 727 characters, or 48.5 per second, which seems plenty fast to me.

Comment: @psusi >>"plenty fast to me"<<. Maybe. But not me. At all. And maybe I'm not the only one.

Comment: The control panel is the same, but the keyboard **fastest** repeat rate configuration is *lower*.

Comment: @OlivierPons, did you measure it?  Subjective terms are unlikely to get anywhere.  If you can measure a specific drop in repeat rate with the setting all the way up, then you should file a bug report.

Comment: @OlivierPons, for comparison, this windows 7 machine I am on right now is set as high as it will go and I'm only getting 29 per second.

Comment: @psusi With Ubuntu 10.04, when I turn the knob up to full and run wc -c in a terminal, then hold down a key for 15 seconds, then hit ctrl-d to end, I get 1507 characters, or ~100 per second, *which seems plenty fast to me there*. It's **twice your rate**.

Comment: @OlivierPons, now you have enough specifics to file a bug report, though I wouldn't be surprised if the change was intentional... 100 cps seems ridiculously fast.  I can't help but ask what you are doing that wants such a fast repeat rate.

Comment: @psusi `0_0` -> Should I have to explain *in depth* why some people can type faster than the others? It's not uncommon to want to scroll very fast down, up, or in command line to go quickly in the middle, and so on. I have a blank "DAS Keyboard" if you need to see the kind of people I am. Anyway it very feels like slower with Ubuntu > 10.04 and there was absolutely no need for Canonical to remove very fast speed. It just frustrates people like me, and doesn't help in any way other ones who don't need it.

Comment: @OlivierPons - typing speed for individual keystrikes and repeat rate for a held down key don't seem the same to me

Comment: You're right. This is the *repeat rate* that has changed. And I still don't see any need to lower the maximum speed.

Comment: Can we move to chat? Please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the UI for this is especially intuitive but, I find it hard to believe that the available settings are not adequate for your needs.

On v3.26.2 at least, the closer you drag the bar to the left the faster the repeat is. This is equivalent to the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat-interval 0
```